# Access videowriter from non gui thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, kinect

I have a gui thread and a worker thread.
What I want to do is to save a videostream (recorded from kinect) in a video locally with a specific fps rate.
What I'm not shure about is, which videostream object I can point my threads to. I am currently using Aforge in C#.

Could it work like this:

```
Thread(GUI){
 VideoStream stream = new VideoStream;
 CallWorkerThread(stream);
}

Thread(Worker){
CreateStreamData();
return data;
}
```

Would this work?

Comment: The thread can't return a value, the easiest way would be:
    data = CallWorkerThread(stream);
But I'm pretty sure thats not possible?